# What is the current status of Stack Overflow in Portuguese?

Tags: support, email, private-beta

I received an e-mail asking me to join the private beta of Stack Overflow in Portuguese, the guy who wrote the e-mail said that I needed to fill a form with my e-mail address (it was a Google Forms form), so I did it. But I have not received any other news about it since November 22nd (the day I received the e-mail). Does someone know anything about it? Did it start already? He wrote that I'd have to wait in a queue, but I filled the form 2 hours after having received the e-mail, so it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: I missed that email, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Stack Overflow in Portuguese Beta is **not** open yet, but it's coming in a couple of weeks.

The proposal is quite old and we had no idea how many people were still interested in joining the site. That's why we asked you to fill that form, so people who are still actively interested on the site can get in first.

As Anna said, this isn't like our other Beta sites. A lot had to be done on both the tech and community sides. Some things are gonna work differently on SO in Portuguese and you'll have more details when it opens.

Please note that not everyone will get in on day one. The invites will go out for the people who replied first, respecting the order in which they replied.

Sorry the email gave out the impression that the Beta was open. It'll just be a little bit longer.

---

On 2013-12-11, the site's [is now live](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). For now, it is in private beta, only opened to users who committed to the proposal on Area 51.

Comment: What is Portugese for "6-8 weeks"?

Comment: @Oddthinking "de 6-8 semanas". And yes, that's pretty much it :p